# Erro Undefined property

Tags: php, laravel, acl

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao clicar em permissões, botão que direciona para esse controller:

**Erro:**

> Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\RolesController::$role

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Role;

class RolesController extends Controller
{
//Exibe Lista de Roles
public function ListRoles(role $role)
{
    $roles = $role->all();

    return view('Roles/roles', compact('roles'));
}


//Exibe Formulário de edição
public function edit($idRole)
{
    $role = role::find($idRole);

    if(empty($role)){
        return view('alert');
    }

    return view('Roles/roles-update', compact('role'));
}


//Salva alterações do formulário de edição
public function save($idRole)
{
    $name = Request()->input('name');
    $label = Request()->input('label');

    $role = role::find($idRole);
    $role->name = $name;
    $role->label = $label;
    $role->save();

    return redirect()->action('RolesController@ListRoles')->withInput();
}


//Deletar uma Role
public function delete($idRole)
{
    $role = role::find($idRole);
    $role->delete();

    return redirect()->action('RolesController@ListRoles');
}


//enviar permissao da role para a view de permissao da role
public function permissions($id)
{
    $role = $this->role->find($id);

    $permissions = $role->permissions;

    return view('roles/permissions', compact('role', 'permissions'));
}
}
```

**RESOLVIDO:**

```
    public function permissions($idRole)
    {
       $role = role::find($idRole);

       $permissions = $role->permissions;

       return view('roles/permissions', compact('role', 'permissions'));
    }
```

Comment: O erro basicamente está te falando que o método/propriedade `role` não existe. Verifique se este está presente no controller.

Comment: Método role está presente

Comment: Posso publicar todo o controller se ajudar

Comment: Ajuda sim. Coloque o código todo para facilitar entendimento.

Comment: só não identei certinho, mas da pra entender

Comment: no erro é especificado que ocorre na linha 61, ou seja, onde eu tinha mostrado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A propriedade `roles` para `$this` não existe realmente. No início da sua classe, declare:

```
private $role;
```

Que ela existirá, assim evitando o erro atual na linha 61, mas quando você for chamar `$this->roles` isso provavelmente retornará `null`, então você deve criar um Construct ou PreDispatch, depende do seu Framework para definir quais serão seus roles.

Comment: retornou null mesmo. Sou iniciante então não entendo o que seria um contruct/ PreDispatch. Tem como me explicar, pf?

Comment: Qual framework você utiliza?

Comment: comecei a usar o Laravel

Comment: Não uso Laravel, mas creio que seja algo do tipo `public function __invoke($id) { /* aqui vai o código */  }` Isso é uma função que é chamada antes de qualquer função ou ação do seu controlador, então nela você seta seus roles, dando pro parâmetro `$this->roles`  o valor de onde eles deveriam vir inicialmente, como de um bd por exemplo.

Comment: Vou procurar entender como funciona. Vlw pela ajuda.

Comment: Olá, apenas para seu conhecimento, consegui resolver meu problema, editarei minha pergunta colocando a resposta a seguir.

Comment: Opa. Que bom! Coloque a resposta sim, para que outras pessoas também possam ser ajudadas futuramente!